# Where do I turn off the ActiveX and plugins warning in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-server-2008-r2

I get several warnings on every page which I visit asking me "Do you want to allow software such as ActiveX controls and plug-ins to run?".

Where do I turn this off? The machine is a Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Launch Internet Explorer -> Tools -> Internet Options. Click on security tab, Click on Custom level and change as you desire. I'd be careful above allowing Allowing ActiveX controls on an (I'm assuming) a server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're versed in IT Security or at least have some experience regarding security, I'd recommend NOT to disable it.

Especially if it's a server machine! ActiveX can be one of the worst security risks.